# Copy from word, paste to niceedit and remove word tags

Tags: javascript, ms-word, nicedit

I tried to copy text from MS Word and paste it into the niceditor on my web application, it is formatted based on the MS Word formatting.
I need to remove the word formatting on text before save the content in niceeditor

Comment: "special paste" (paste without formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Guys I found the Solutions from google. Solution is, Change particular class in nicEdit plugin
Replace nicEditorInstance as follows in your nicedit.js file

```js
var nicEditorInstance=bkClass.extend({
    isSelected : false,
    construct : function(e,options,nicEditor) {
        this.ne = nicEditor;
        this.elm = this.e = e;
        this.options = options || {};

        newX = parseInt(e.getStyle('width')) || e.clientWidth;
        newY = parseInt(e.getStyle('height')) || e.clientHeight;
        this.initialHeight = newY-8;

        var isTextarea = (e.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "textarea");
        if(isTextarea || this.options.hasPanel) {
            var ie7s = (bkLib.isMSIE && !((typeof document.body.style.maxHeight != "undefined") && document.compatMode == "CSS1Compat"))
            var s = {width: newX+'px', border : '2px solid #F1F1F1', borderTop : 0, overflowY : 'auto', overflowX: 'hidden' };
            s[(ie7s) ? 'height' : 'maxHeight'] = (this.ne.options.maxHeight) ? this.ne.options.maxHeight+'px' : null;
            this.editorContain = new bkElement('DIV').setStyle(s).appendBefore(e);

            /* CLEAN WORD PASTE MOD */
            //var editorElm = new bkElement('DIV').setAttributes({id : e.id}).setStyle({width : (newX-8)+'px', margin: '4px', minHeight : newY+'px'}).addClass('main').appendTo(this.editorContain);
            var editorElm = new bkElement('DIV').setStyle({width : (newX-8)+'px', margin: '4px', minHeight : newY+'px'}).addClass('main').appendTo(this.editorContain);


            e.setStyle({display : 'none'});
            editorElm.innerHTML = e.innerHTML;
            if(isTextarea) {
                editorElm.setContent(e.value);
                this.copyElm = e;
                var f = e.parentTag('FORM');
                if(f) { bkLib.addEvent( f, 'submit', this.saveContent.closure(this)); }
            }
            editorElm.setStyle((ie7s) ? {height : newY+'px'} : {overflow: 'hidden'});
            this.elm = editorElm;

        }
        this.ne.addEvent('blur',this.blur.closure(this));

        this.init();
        this.blur();
    },

    init : function() {
        this.elm.setAttribute('contentEditable','true');
        if(this.getContent() == "") {
            this.setContent('<br />');
        }
        this.instanceDoc = document.defaultView;
        this.elm.addEvent('mousedown',this.selected.closureListener(this)).addEvent('keypress',this.keyDown.closureListener(this)).addEvent('focus',this.selected.closure(this)).addEvent('blur',this.blur.closure(this)).addEvent('keyup',this.selected.closure(this));
        this.ne.fireEvent('add',this);

        /* CLEAN WORD PASTE MOD */
        this.elm.addEvent('paste',this.initPasteClean.closureListener(this));
    },

    initPasteClean : function() {
        this.pasteCache = this.getElm().innerHTML;
        setTimeout(this.pasteClean.closure(this),100);
    },

    /* CLEAN WORD PASTE MOD : pasteClean method added for clean word paste */
    pasteClean : function() {
        var matchedHead = "";
        var matchedTail = "";
        var newContent = this.getElm().innerHTML;
        this.ne.fireEvent("get",this);
        var newContentStart = 0;
        var newContentFinish = 0;
        var newSnippet = "";
        var tempNode = document.createElement("div");

        /* Find start of both strings that matches */

        for (newContentStart = 0; newContent.charAt(newContentStart) == this.pasteCache.charAt(newContentStart); newContentStart++)
        {
            matchedHead += this.pasteCache.charAt(newContentStart);
        }

        /* If newContentStart is inside a HTML tag, move to opening brace of tag */
        for (var i = newContentStart; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (this.pasteCache.charAt(i) == "<")
            {
                newContentStart = i;
                matchedHead = this.pasteCache.substring(0, newContentStart);

                break;
            }
            else if(this.pasteCache.charAt(i) == ">")
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        newContent = this.reverse(newContent);
        this.pasteCache = this.reverse(this.pasteCache);

        /* Find end of both strings that matches */
        for (newContentFinish = 0; newContent.charAt(newContentFinish) == this.pasteCache.charAt(newContentFinish); newContentFinish++)
        {
            matchedTail += this.pasteCache.charAt(newContentFinish);
        }

        /* If newContentFinish is inside a HTML tag, move to closing brace of tag */
        for (var i = newContentFinish; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (this.pasteCache.charAt(i) == ">")
            {
                newContentFinish = i;
                matchedTail = this.pasteCache.substring(0, newContentFinish);

                break;
            }
            else if(this.pasteCache.charAt(i) == "<")
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        matchedTail = this.reverse(matchedTail);

        /* If there's no difference in pasted content */
        if (newContentStart == newContent.length - newContentFinish)
        {
            return false;
        }

        newContent = this.reverse(newContent);
        newSnippet = newContent.substring(newContentStart, newContent.length - newContentFinish);
        newSnippet = this.validTags(newSnippet);

        /* Replace opening bold tags with strong */
        newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<b(\s+|>)/g, "<strong$1");
        /* Replace closing bold tags with closing strong */
        newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<\/b(\s+|>)/g, "</strong$1");

        /* Replace italic tags with em */
        newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<i(\s+|>)/g, "<em$1");
        /* Replace closing italic tags with closing em */
        newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<\/i(\s+|>)/g, "</em$1");

        /* strip out comments -cgCraft */
        newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<!(?:--[\s\S]*?--\s*)?>\s*/g, "");

        /* strip out &nbsp; -cgCraft */
        newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, " ");
        /* strip out extra spaces -cgCraft */
        newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/ <\//gi, "</");

        while (newSnippet.indexOf("  ") != -1) {
            var anArray = newSnippet.split("  ")
            newSnippet = anArray.join(" ")
        }

        /* strip &nbsp; -cgCraft */
        newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "");

        /* Strip out unaccepted attributes */

        newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, function(match)
            {
                match = match.replace(/ ([^=]+)="[^"]*"/g, function(match2, attributeName)
                    {
                        if (attributeName == "alt" || attributeName == "href" || attributeName == "src" || attributeName == "title")
                        {
                            return match2;
                        }

                        return "";
                    });

                return match;
            }
            );

        /* Final cleanout for MS Word cruft */
        newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<\?xml[^>]*>/g, "");
        newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<[^ >]+:[^>]*>/g, "");
        newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<\/[^ >]+:[^>]*>/g, "");

        /* remove undwanted tags */
        newSnippet = newSnippet.replace(/<(div|span|style|meta|link){1}.*?>/gi,'');

        this.content = matchedHead + newSnippet + matchedTail;
        this.ne.fireEvent("set",this);
        this.elm.innerHTML = this.content;
    },

    reverse : function(sentString) {
        var theString = "";
        for (var i = sentString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            theString += sentString.charAt(i);
        }
        return theString;
    },

    /* CLEAN WORD PASTE MOD : validTags method added for clean word paste */
    validTags : function(snippet) {
        var theString = snippet;

        /* Replace uppercase element names with lowercase */
        theString = theString.replace(/<[^> ]*/g, function(match){return match.toLowerCase();});

        /* Replace uppercase attribute names with lowercase */
        theString = theString.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, function(match) {
            match = match.replace(/ [^=]+=/g, function(match2){return match2.toLowerCase();});
            return match;
        });

        /* Put quotes around unquoted attributes */
        theString = theString.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, function(match) {
            match = match.replace(/( [^=]+=)([^"][^ >]*)/g, "$1\"$2\"");
            return match;
        });

        return theString;
    },

    remove : function() {
        this.saveContent();
        if(this.copyElm || this.options.hasPanel) {
            this.editorContain.remove();
            this.e.setStyle({'display' : 'block'});
            this.ne.removePanel();
        }
        this.disable();
        this.ne.fireEvent('remove',this);
    },

    disable : function() {
        this.elm.setAttribute('contentEditable','false');
    },

    getSel : function() {
        return (window.getSelection) ? window.getSelection() : document.selection;
    },

    getRng : function() {
        var s = this.getSel();
        if(!s) { return null; }
        return (s.rangeCount > 0) ? s.getRangeAt(0) : s.createRange();
    },

    selRng : function(rng,s) {
        if(window.getSelection) {
            s.removeAllRanges();
            s.addRange(rng);
        } else {
            rng.select();
        }
    },

    selElm : function() {
        var r = this.getRng();
        if(r.startContainer) {
            var contain = r.startContainer;
            if(r.cloneContents().childNodes.length == 1) {
                for(var i=0;i<contain.childNodes.length;i++) {
                    var rng = contain.childNodes[i].ownerDocument.createRange();
                    rng.selectNode(contain.childNodes[i]);
                    if(r.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.START_TO_START,rng) != 1 &&
                        r.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_END,rng) != -1) {
                        return $BK(contain.childNodes[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return $BK(contain);
        } else {
            return $BK((this.getSel().type == "Control") ? r.item(0) : r.parentElement());
        }
    },

    saveRng : function() {
        this.savedRange = this.getRng();
        this.savedSel = this.getSel();
    },

    restoreRng : function() {
        if(this.savedRange) {
            this.selRng(this.savedRange,this.savedSel);
        }
    },

    keyDown : function(e,t) {
        if(e.ctrlKey) {
            this.ne.fireEvent('key',this,e);
        }
    },

    selected : function(e,t) {
        if(!t) {t = this.selElm()}
        if(!e.ctrlKey) {
            var selInstance = this.ne.selectedInstance;
            if(selInstance != this) {
                if(selInstance) {
                    this.ne.fireEvent('blur',selInstance,t);
                }
                this.ne.selectedInstance = this;
                this.ne.fireEvent('focus',selInstance,t);
            }
            this.ne.fireEvent('selected',selInstance,t);
            this.isFocused = true;
            this.elm.addClass('selected');
        }
        return false;
    },

    blur : function() {
        this.isFocused = false;
        this.elm.removeClass('selected');
    },

    saveContent : function() {
        if(this.copyElm || this.options.hasPanel) {
            this.ne.fireEvent('save',this);
            (this.copyElm) ? this.copyElm.value = this.getContent() : this.e.innerHTML = this.getContent();
        }
    },

    getElm : function() {
        return this.elm;
    },

    getContent : function() {
        this.content = this.getElm().innerHTML;
        this.ne.fireEvent('get',this);
        return this.content;
    },

    setContent : function(e) {
        this.content = e;
        this.ne.fireEvent('set',this);
        this.elm.innerHTML = this.content;
    },

    nicCommand : function(cmd,args) {
        document.execCommand(cmd,false,args);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to remove all editing. Paste the content in notepad and then to niceeditor.

Comment: that is possibly the simplest solution there is.

Comment: Thanks Vimla but I am using it for all my contact description in my Application, I need to copy from ms word